# Testing REST framework JWT Auth error

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

So i was trying to test out the django restframework authentication token, but i ran into this error when trying to retrieve the token.

`Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'X'.`

`+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand`

can someone explain to me what this means, and does anyone know the solution

this is what i typed into the cmd:
`curl -X POST -d "username=(username)&password=(password)" (the url to token)`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use the `curl` command in PowerShell. If this is the case, you have to install it first. See [this post](http://thesociablegeek.com/azure/using-curl-in-powershell/) on how to install cURL in Windows and use it in PowerShell.